# Token pasting for generic struct

Tags: c, structure, c-preprocessor

I am attempting to define some simple generic structures in C using token pasting. An example of which is below:-

```
#define VECTOR(type, dimension, name) \
    typedef struct Vector_##type{ \
        type data[##dimension##]; \
        int dim = dimension; \
    }##name##;
VECTOR(int, 3, Vector3i)
```

To my understanding the token pasting is necessary on lines 2 and 5 due to the embedding of the paramaters, and is not necessary on line 4 for the opposite reason.

However I appear to be missing something in my understanding as the simple example above causes the following errors:-

```
pasting formed '[3', an invalid preprocessing token VECTOR(int, 3, Vector3i)

pasting formed '3]', an invalid preprocessing token VECTOR(int, 3, Vector3i)

expected member name or ';' after declaration specifiers
VECTOR(int, 3, Vector3i)
~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~
```

Given the above errors, what have I missed and what is the appropriate way to define generic structures in pure C?

Comment: `int dim = dim;` ain't gonna work.

Comment: I realised this also after I posted. Edited.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't need the token pasting operation for the size or the type-name.

It's used to actually create a single token from multiple, so for `Vector_##type` it makes sense to create a single `Vector_int` token.

It doesn't make sense in `[##dim##]` where it would attempt to create a ***single*** `[3]` token. That should be three different and separate tokens: `[` followed by `3` followed by `]` which you get by using `[dim]` in the macro.

It's the same with the `typedef` name after the structure.